# Use Express post request to emit Socket.io

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I want get username when user post it, but io.sockets.emit is not working. However, When i didn't put io.sockets.emit on app.post, It is working.

my html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="chat" id="main" method="post">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="id" name="username" value="" placeholder=" " required />
                <label for="id">暱稱</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="key" name="key" value="" placeholder=" " />
                <label for="key">房號</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" value="加入房間" class="btn">加入房間</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

my js

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('joinRoom', username => {
        console.log(username);
        console.log("joinRoom");
    });
    socket.on('chat message', msg => {
        const user = getCurrentUser(socket.id);
        console.log(user);
        io.emit('chat message',  msg);
  });
});
app.post('/chat', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    io.sockets.emit('joinRoom', "aa")
    console.log(req.body)
    res.sendFile('public/chat.html', { root: __dirname })
});
```

'joinRoom' seems not receive anything.

Comment: If your POST is a browser-driven form post (not an ajax post from Javascript), then the current page is destroyed after a POST and that kills the socket.io connection so it will miss your `io.emit()`.  A new page (from the response to the form post) is loaded in place of the old one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! so I need to use AJAX to solve this problem?

Comment: I depends upon what you're trying to accomplish with the joinRoom message.  `io.emit('joinRoom', ...)` is attempting to send a message to all the connected clients, but you only show a server-side handler for that message.  That has me confused.  Perhaps you actually mean to notify your server rather than the client?  If that's the case, you don't need to send the message to the client first.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks!